# jquery функция $

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, что это за способ вызова функции $ и как он работает?

```
$('select[name=\'recurring_id\'], input[name=\'quantity\']')
```

Меня смущает запятая внутри кавычек.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Выбирает все элементы `<select name='recurring_id'>` и `<input name='quantity'>`.

А запятая означает список селекторов.

[http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Групповые_селекторы](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)